# Rabbitmq listener across machine not detected

Tags: linux, networking, rabbitmq, queue

I have multiple rabbitmq listeners running across linux boxes. However when I  post a message A (which takes some time to process , around 5 mins), new messages after A wait in the queue  till A is processed , instead of going to the next idle listener.
Thus I am not able to take advantage of multiple listeners